# Multiple Serial connection from Arduino to Qt Creator and Matlab

Tags: matlab, qt, arduino, serial-port

I am currently doing a project that uses this 3 softwares. Qt, Arduino Uno and MAtlab.

In my project, I was planning to use Qt to transmit an input value into Arduino in which Arduino will give a feedback in return, in which the feedback output is serially received by Matlab.

I have tried performing the serial connection, unfortunately Arduino Uno can only initiate serial connection with either one of them, and not both.

Is there any way to perform multiple transmit/received method between this Qt-arduino-Matlab serial connection?

Thank you for your time and aid

Comment: Why are you not using only QT or only Matlab ?

Comment: @obchardon it is actually a JV project, so my partner is using matlab and I am using Qt, so I am hoping to get serial communication between these 3 softwares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an Arduino device as serial port, and you want to communicate with it from Matlab and Qt simultaneously under the same host computer.

Under Windows, there seems no simple solution, unless you write some low level code to open the device with special share mode.

Under unix, you can open the serial port from Qt (it seems this works for you), and if needed, you start Matlab as sudo, so you have full control over the serial port, which allows you to open it again.

Comment: Thank you @XiangruiLi, appreciate your opinion. Guess that I need to figure out some other methods to fulfill my requirements, then